# How I can show a innerHTML inside another one?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

Question: In this code I´m traying to show the local storage in DOM, how I can show the "li" of the second for inside of the "ul" in the first for?

to show it like this? :

```
<div id = "receta${[i]}">
      <h2>${recetasLocales[i].nombreReceta}</h2>
      <ul><li>${recetasLocales[i].ingredientes[n].nombre}</li></ul>
      <p>${recetasLocales[i].procedimiento}</p>
</div>
```

---

This is the code I wrote, if you see in the case both innerHTML obviouly will be separate and I dont want that.

```
mostrar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let recetasLocales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recetasLocales'))

  for (let i = 0; i < recetasLocales.length; i++) {
    listaReceta.innerHTML +=`
    <div id = "receta${[i]}">
      <h2>${recetasLocales[i].nombreReceta}</h2>
      <ul></ul>
      <p>${recetasLocales[i].procedimiento}</p>
    </div>
    `
    for (let n = 0; n < recetasLocales[i].ingredientes.length; n++) {
      listaReceta.innerHTML += `
      <li>${recetasLocales[i].ingredientes[n].nombre}</li>
      `
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this kind of thing without concatenating strings all the time is to use `document.createElement()` and `appendChild()`.

> Note this uses `textContent` which prevents [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) as it is not parsed as HTML.

See this minimal example.

```js
const someValues = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
];

// create div which contains the lists
const div = document.createElement("div");

for (let i = 0; i < someValues.length; i++) {
  // create heading
  const heading = document.createElement("h2");
  heading.textContent = `My heading for element ${i}`;

  // create list
  const list = document.createElement("ul");
  for (let j = 0; j < someValues[i].length; j++) {
    const element = someValues[i][j];
    // create a new list item
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = element;
    // add list item to list
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }

  // adding it all together
  div.appendChild(heading);
  div.appendChild(list);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  const content = document.getElementById("test");
  content.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I made this but a want to do differents divs, I saw this is in all in one div

Comment: No problem, just create another `div` using `const anotherDiv = document.createElement("div")` and use `appendChild()` there to append the list items on there which you want to have in the second `div`.

Comment: I have one question, the thing is when I submit my form with a submit event doesn´t show in DOM startight away, it show it when I refresh. How I can fix that?

Comment: Have a look at [event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) and [JS form validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of performing this operation.
One way is to have a string variable and manipulate it to your liking.

Example:

```
mostrar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let recetasLocales = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recetasLocales'))

  for (let i = 0; i < recetasLocales.length; i++) {
    let str =`
    <div id = "receta${[i]}">
      <h2>${recetasLocales[i].nombreReceta}</h2>
      <ul>
    `

    for (let n = 0; n < recetasLocales[i].ingredientes.length; n++) {
      str += `
      <li>${recetasLocales[i].ingredientes[n].nombre}</li>
      `
    }

    str+=`</ul>
      <p>${recetasLocales[i].procedimiento}</p>
    </div>`

    listaReceta.innerHTML=str
  }
```

Comment: I tried this one and it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" , in the last line of code "listaRecetya.innerHTML=str"

Comment: @JavierPérez How are you generating the "_listaReceta_" variable ?